# Codeigniter setup throws php error in core/codeIgnitor.php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have installed apache and php through `sudo apt-get install` command. I changed the apache htdocs to point to the codeigniter code base. Is there any configuration I am missing?

Configuration:

> Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
>
> PHP 5.4.4-14+deb7u9 (cli) (built: Apr 18 2014 14:34:31)  Copyright (c)
>   1997-2012 The PHP Group Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012
>   Zend Technologies
>
> OS: Debian 7

Error message when the point the browser to the IP (which probably triggers index.php).

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: CI

Filename: core/CodeIgniter.php

Line Number: 323
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: CI

Filename: core/CodeIgniter.php

Line Number: 331
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array

Filename: core/CodeIgniter.php

Line Number: 331
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given

Filename: core/CodeIgniter.php

Line Number: 331
```

But, all this code belongs to the codeignitor core code base. What am I missing?

Comment: You should check your `application/config/config.php` file and your `application/config/database.php` file, I had a similar problem where I had the database name incorrect in , the setup went crazy throwing similar errors like yours.

Comment: Thanks, tried that but did not work. :(